# Piping to notify-send in chunks

Tags: unix, mocha.js, piping

I'm trying to compose a command to send unix output to my desktop notifications using the `notify-send` cl tool. I have the following command:

`mocha -w | while read SPAM_OUT; do notify-send -t 5000 "mocha:" "$SPAM_OUT"; done`

Which does what I want, except that I'd like it to spit out the entirety of mocha's output in a single notification every time mocha barfs out some new stuff. Right now, I get a notification for every single line, which is profoundly annoying.

If there are any tools which should already do this for me, I'd be interested in them too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you expect:

```
notify-send -t 5000 "mocha:" "$(mocha -w)"
```

This puts the complete output of `mocha -w` in the fourth argument of `notify-send`

If mocha -w does not terminate, the bash-specific `read -t` comes in handy:

```
mocha -w | ( while true; do MSG=""; while read -t .1 LINE; do MSG="$MSG $LINE"; done; if [ "$MSG" != "" ]; then notify-send -t 5000 "$MSG"; fi; done; )
```

This aggregates all lines which come in in the timeframe of 1/10th second in one message. You can adjust this timeout to fit your needs. Note that this is bash-specific, other shells (i.e. dash) may not support it.

Comment: The issue with this command is that `mocha -w` does not halt, the `-w` is a 'watch' argument which listens for changes to the files and retests perpetually. So I'd like to send output to notify-send perpetually, but in chunks instead of line-by-line

Comment: @user2130130 I understand, in this case I have another proposal, see edit

Comment: This is elegant and does exactly what I want it to do, thank you!

I get that $LINE is being concatinated to $MSG until there's a lull in the piped input, and there's a conditional statement preventing `notify-send` from notifying empty input, but what exactly is `read` supposed to be used for in general?

Comment: Also, is LINE an argument to read? An arbitrary variable name for storing chunks or is it s name significant?

Comment: @user2130130 `read` reads in a line from some source, usually stdin if not specified otherwise, and stores it in the specified variable, `LINE` in this case. The name can be arbitrary and has no special meaning. `-t .1` causes `read` to return if no input has been received after 1/10th second.